# How do I escape double quotes to \" in my entire xml string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, xcode

Very simple question but giving me hard time, I want to replace " to \" in my entire xml file. I tried but don't know how to do it.

My try :

```
escapedXMLString = [xml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@"\""];
```

of course above line won't even compile, as I am escaping the double quote. So is there any work around?

Comment: Why do you want to escape double quotes in an xml?

Comment: I am sending an xml string to a server, and assuming the .Net code on  server which process that xml is expecting sanitised version of XML. as it breaks if I send xml with double quotes in it.

Comment: A double quote is a valid character in an XML e.g. it (or a single quote) is normally used with attribute values.

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think the real issue might be that your XML file has a double quote inside an attribute value. If that's the case, you can escape it by substituting it with `&quot;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the \ to escape the " in the string for the find and a \ for the \" in the replace.

```
escapedXMLString = [xml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

Comment: Spot on, seems like I am loosing my skills day by day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `[xml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]);`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate this literal for something more involved you might consider using a tool like this:

http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output

to accomplish the work for you.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050827/411401).